# WordPress thinks my custom theme is a theme in the public theme repository

Tags: themes

I'm currently developing a custom theme for a client, and all of a sudden WordPres tells me there's an update to version 1.4. This is obviously wrong, but WordPress thinks my theme is the same as https://wordpress.org/themes/risa/

Here's my style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: RISA AS 2017
Theme URI: http://risa.no
Author: AD. Moment AS
Author URI: http://admoment.no
Description: Nettsidene til RISA AS
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: LICENSE
Text Domain: risa_as
Tags:

*/
```

I changed the name of the theme and the Text Domain from risa and risa respectively, but WordPress still thinks this is the same theme.

How can I change the name of my theme to not overlap with the one in the public theme repository?

Comment: Is your own theme's folder named `risa`?

Comment: It is … Thank you for reminding me, that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure your own theme folder is not named the same as the theme folder in the WordPress repo. When checking for updates, WordPress scans theme folder names, not the theme title or other meta in the `style.css` file.

Comment: Yes, thank you. As I pointed out above, this fixed the problem.

Comment: I added this as an answer - rather than a comment - so you can accept it as a correct answer.